# objective c - convert mpmediaitem to ogg vorbis

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ogg, mpmediaitem

i found (customizing a method i found) a way to convert a MpMediaItem and to obtain a mp3 file. Probably it's not the best way but it's working.

Is there a way to obtain an *.ogg file instead of *.mp3 ? What would be the proper approach?

This is the method i use to get the *.mp3 file:

```
    -(void)exportMP3:(NSURL*)url toFileUrl:(NSString*)fileURL
{
    AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVAssetReader *reader=[[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *myOutputs =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(id track in [asset tracks])
    {
        AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output=[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:track outputSettings:nil];
        [myOutputs addObject:output];   
        [reader addOutput:output];
    }
    [reader startReading];
    NSFileHandle *fileHandle ;
    NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:fileURL])
    {
        [fm createFileAtPath:fileURL contents:[[NSData alloc] init] attributes:nil];
    }else{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURL];
        [fm removeItemAtURL:url error:nil];
        [fm createFileAtPath:fileURL contents:[[NSData alloc] init] attributes:nil];

    }
    fileHandle=[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileURL];    
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];

    AVAssetReaderOutput *output=[myOutputs objectAtIndex:0];
    int totalBuff=0;
    int test = 1;
    while(test == 1)
    {
        CMSampleBufferRef ref=[output copyNextSampleBuffer];

        if(ref==NULL)
            test = 0;

        if(ref==NULL)
            break;
        //copy data to file
        //read next one
        AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
        NSMutableData *data;
        CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
        CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(ref, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);

        for( int y=0; y<audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++ )
        {
            AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
            void *frame = audioBuffer.mData;

            data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];
        }
        totalBuff++;
        NSLog(@"\n%d\n",totalBuff);

        int time = [self.mediaPlayer durationOfCurrentItem];

        if (totalBuff * 2 <= time + 1)        
            [fileHandle writeData:data];

    }
    [fileHandle closeFile];
}
```

Comment: If your code for encoding MP3 works correctly, this would be a major breakthrough because it is a generally accepted fact that without a thrid party library like [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/), it is impossible to encode audio to the MP3 format in ios. Are you sure this works, and does not simply play because of the goodwill of an audio player, which accepts some other format inside of an mp3 file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [libvorbis](http://xiph.org/vorbis/) to encode PCM data to Vorbis.

Comment: How long would take to get the ogg file for an average mp3? Let's say that the mp3 song is about 3 minutes long. The method i'm using to get the mp3 file takes up to 2 seconds sometimes. I'm concerned about lag. Thanks

Comment: @SylBurlac media conversion is computationally expensive. You should do this in a background thread.

Comment: I did it in a background thread, but the conversion starts when i hit the play button (i use this to stream over dlna to a device which supports only ogg format) and i'm worried about the time interval between hitting the play button and the time interval until the device starts to play. Thanks a lot for your answer